# alinear texto e imagenes en vertical vista laravel

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap

quiero alinear una imagen con textos de forma vertical.

Actualmente lo tengo de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he aqui el código

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="d-block" for="file_hoja_solicitud"><b>Imagen</b></label>
   @if($failuresDetail->name_random_file_solicitud)
      <embed   style="width: 15%; height: 15%; float: left;" src="{{route("admin.equipment.case.download",['namefile'=>$failuresDetail->name_random_file_solicitud])}}"></embed>
      <a href="{{route("admin.equipment.case.download",['namefile'=>$failuresDetail->name_random_file_solicitud])}}" class="mt-1 d-inline-block">DESCARGAR</a>
      <div class="form-check ml-3 mt-1 d-inline-block">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input id="failure_close_check_f1" name="failure_close_check_f1" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
          Desea cambiar el archivo?
        </label>
      </div>
   @endif
   <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file_hoja_solicitud" name="file_hoja_solicitud" placeholder="Ingrese número de serie" 
            {{($failuresDetail->name_random_file_solicitud)?"style=display:none disabled":""}}>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es algo así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Metemos el embed dentro de un contenedor y después le añadimos en css para limpiar el float.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="d-block" for="file_hoja_solicitud"><b>Imagen</b></label>
   @if($failuresDetail->name_random_file_solicitud)
      <div class="embed-container">
              <embed src="{{route("admin.equipment.case.download",['namefile'=>$failuresDetail->name_random_file_solicitud])}}">
      </div>
      <a href="{{route("admin.equipment.case.download",['namefile'=>$failuresDetail->name_random_file_solicitud])}}" class="mt-1 d-inline-block">DESCARGAR</a>
      <div class="form-check ml-3 mt-1 d-inline-block">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input id="failure_close_check_f1" name="failure_close_check_f1" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
          Desea cambiar el archivo?
        </label>
      </div>
   @endif
   <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file_hoja_solicitud" name="file_hoja_solicitud" placeholder="Ingrese número de serie" 
            {{($failuresDetail->name_random_file_solicitud)?"style=display:none disabled":""}}>
</div>
```

CSS a añadir:

```
.embed-container:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.embed-container>embed {
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: me ha funcionado